# C# lambda expression with sub query

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I need to convert the following SQL statement to a lambda expression so that my C# application can access the data using entity framework.  I am struggling to implement the sub query in a lambda expression.
The SQL statement is

```
SELECT columnName1
FROM tableName
WHERE columnName2 = (SELECT MAX(columnName2) FROM tableName)
```

In the lambda expression I am familiar with the .Select() and the .First() but can't get the syntax quite right for the .Where() when it needs to reference the sub query.

Comment: You should post the C# you attempted to write.

Comment: Instead of a subquery you can order on `columnName2` and just take the first row like `tableName.OrderByDescending(x => x.columnName2).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @juharr what if there are multiple records that have the max value for `columnName2`?

Comment: @user1538301 Yeah, it would need a GroupBy as well `tableName.GroupBy(x => x.columnName2).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming tableName is an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` has members `columnName1` and `columnName2` and `columnName2` is a decimal, int, float, long or double:

```cs
tableName
   .Where(row => row.columnName2 == tableName.Max(row => row.columnName2))
   .Select(row => row.columnName1);
```